# how to stop selenium installation on "onPrepare" hook when using webdriver IO (wdio V7)

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, webdriver-io

when i run my test using wdio it fails on "onPrepare" hook as it tries to install selenium server by throwing this error

```
2021-06-01T16:10:07.130Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onPrepare hook
Error in "getDownloadStream". Could not download https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/3.141/selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar
See more details below:
connect ETIMEDOUT 142.250.74.112:443
2021-06-01T16:11:22.829Z ERROR @wdio/cli:utils: A service failed in the 'onPrepare' hook
RequestError: connect ETIMEDOUT 142.250.74.112:443
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/Users/test/node_modules/got/dist/source/core/index.js:956:111)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:421:26)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:326:22)
    at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
    at ClientRequest.origin.emit (/Users/test/node_modules/@szmarczak/http-timer/dist/source/index.js:39:20)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:427:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at TLSSocket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1144:16)
```

the issue is i don't even want wdio to try and install selenium because i have already installed  it. On WDIO v6 this use to work, if i installed selenium myself before running the test then i don't get this error.

**so what i wanna know is is there a way to stop/skip selenium installation on `onPrepare` hook?**

this is my config file WDIO

```
require('@babel/register');
require('@babel/polyfill');

const drivers = {
  proxy: process.env.proxy,
  baseURL: 'https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com',
  version: '3.141.59',
  ignoreExtraDrivers: true,
  drivers: {
    chrome: {
      version: '88.0.4324.96',
      arch: process.arch,
      baseURL: 'https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com'
    },
    firefox: {
      version: '0.25.0',
      arch: process.arch,
      baseURL: 'https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download'
    }
  }
};

exports.config = {
  runner: 'local',
  specs: ['./browser-tests/specs/**/*.spec.js'],
  exclude: [
    // 'path/to/excluded/files'
  ],
  maxInstances: 10,
  capabilities: [
    {
      maxInstances: 5,
      //
      browserName: 'firefox',
      acceptInsecureCerts: true
    }
  ],
  logLevel: 'debug',
  bail: 0,
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3000',
  waitforTimeout: 10000,
  connectionRetryTimeout: 120000,
  connectionRetryCount: 3,
  skipSeleniumInstall: true,
  services: [
    [
      'selenium-standalone',
      {
        args: { drivers } // drivers to use
      }
    ]
  ],
  framework: 'jasmine',
  reporters: ['spec'],
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I had file wdio.conf.js created automatically at the beginning of installing wdio.

```
exports.config = {
//
// ====================
// Runner Configuration
// ====================
//
//
// ==================
// Specify Test Files
// ==================
// Define which test specs should run. The pattern is relative to the directory
// from which `wdio` was called.
//
// The specs are defined as an array of spec files (optionally using wildcards
// that will be expanded). The test for each spec file will be run in a separate
// worker process. In order to have a group of spec files run in the same worker
// process simply enclose them in an array within the specs array.
//
// If you are calling `wdio` from an NPM script (see https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script),
// then the current working directory is where your `package.json` resides, so `wdio`
// will be called from there.
//
specs: [
    './test/specs/**/*.js'
],
// Patterns to exclude.
exclude: [
    // 'path/to/excluded/files'
],
//
// ============
// Capabilities
// ============
// Define your capabilities here. WebdriverIO can run multiple capabilities at the same
// time. Depending on the number of capabilities, WebdriverIO launches several test
// sessions. Within your capabilities you can overwrite the spec and exclude options in
// order to group specific specs to a specific capability.
//
// First, you can define how many instances should be started at the same time. Let's
// say you have 3 different capabilities (Chrome, Firefox, and Safari) and you have
// set maxInstances to 1; wdio will spawn 3 processes. Therefore, if you have 10 spec
// files and you set maxInstances to 10, all spec files will get tested at the same time
// and 30 processes will get spawned. The property handles how many capabilities
// from the same test should run tests.
//
maxInstances: 10,
//
// If you have trouble getting all important capabilities together, check out the
// Sauce Labs platform configurator - a great tool to configure your capabilities:
// https://saucelabs.com/platform/platform-configurator
//
capabilities: [{

    // maxInstances can get overwritten per capability. So if you have an in-house Selenium
    // grid with only 5 firefox instances available you can make sure that not more than
    // 5 instances get started at a time.
    maxInstances: 5,
    //
    browserName: 'chrome',
    acceptInsecureCerts: true
    // If outputDir is provided WebdriverIO can capture driver session logs
    // it is possible to configure which logTypes to include/exclude.
    // excludeDriverLogs: ['*'], // pass '*' to exclude all driver session logs
    // excludeDriverLogs: ['bugreport', 'server'],
}],
//
// ===================
// Test Configurations
// ===================
// Define all options that are relevant for the WebdriverIO instance here
//
// Level of logging verbosity: trace | debug | info | warn | error | silent
logLevel: 'info',
//
// Set specific log levels per logger
// loggers:
// - webdriver, webdriverio
// - @wdio/browserstack-service, @wdio/devtools-service, @wdio/sauce-service
// - @wdio/mocha-framework, @wdio/jasmine-framework
// - @wdio/local-runner
// - @wdio/sumologic-reporter
// - @wdio/cli, @wdio/config, @wdio/utils
// Level of logging verbosity: trace | debug | info | warn | error | silent
// logLevels: {
//     webdriver: 'info',
//     '@wdio/appium-service': 'info'
// },
//
// If you only want to run your tests until a specific amount of tests have failed use
// bail (default is 0 - don't bail, run all tests).
bail: 0,
//
// Set a base URL in order to shorten url command calls. If your `url` parameter starts
// with `/`, the base url gets prepended, not including the path portion of your baseUrl.
// If your `url` parameter starts without a scheme or `/` (like `some/path`), the base url
// gets prepended directly.
baseUrl: 'http://localhost',
//
// Default timeout for all waitFor* commands.
waitforTimeout: 10000,
//
// Default timeout in milliseconds for request
// if browser driver or grid doesn't send response
connectionRetryTimeout: 120000,
//
// Default request retries count
connectionRetryCount: 3,
//
// Test runner services
// Services take over a specific job you don't want to take care of. They enhance
// your test setup with almost no effort. Unlike plugins, they don't add new
// commands. Instead, they hook themselves up into the test process.
 services: ['selenium-standalone'],

// Framework you want to run your specs with.
// The following are supported: Mocha, Jasmine, and Cucumber
// see also: https://webdriver.io/docs/frameworks
//
// Make sure you have the wdio adapter package for the specific framework installed
// before running any tests.
framework: 'mocha',
//
// The number of times to retry the entire specfile when it fails as a whole
// specFileRetries: 1,
//
// Delay in seconds between the spec file retry attempts
// specFileRetriesDelay: 0,
//
// Whether or not retried specfiles should be retried immediately or deferred to the end of the queue
// specFileRetriesDeferred: false,
//
// Test reporter for stdout.
// The only one supported by default is 'dot'
// see also: https://webdriver.io/docs/dot-reporter
reporters: ['spec'],



//
// Options to be passed to Mocha.
// See the full list at http://mochajs.org/
mochaOpts: {
    ui: 'bdd',
    timeout: 60000
},
//
// =====
// Hooks
// =====
// WebdriverIO provides several hooks you can use to interfere with the test process in order to enhance
// it and to build services around it. You can either apply a single function or an array of
// methods to it. If one of them returns with a promise, WebdriverIO will wait until that promise got
// resolved to continue.
/**
 * Gets executed once before all workers get launched.
 * @param {Object} config wdio configuration object
 * @param {Array.<Object>} capabilities list of capabilities details
 */
// onPrepare: function (config, capabilities) {
// },
/**
 * Gets executed before a worker process is spawned and can be used to initialise specific service
 * for that worker as well as modify runtime environments in an async fashion.
 * @param  {String} cid      capability id (e.g 0-0)
 * @param  {[type]} caps     object containing capabilities for session that will be spawn in the worker
 * @param  {[type]} specs    specs to be run in the worker process
 * @param  {[type]} args     object that will be merged with the main configuration once worker is initialized
 * @param  {[type]} execArgv list of string arguments passed to the worker process
 */
// onWorkerStart: function (cid, caps, specs, args, execArgv) {
// },
/**
 * Gets executed just after a worker process has exited.
 * @param  {String} cid      capability id (e.g 0-0)
 * @param  {Number} exitCode 0 - success, 1 - fail
 * @param  {[type]} specs    specs to be run in the worker process
 * @param  {Number} retries  number of retries used
 */
// onWorkerEnd: function (cid, exitCode, specs, retries) {
// },
/**
 * Gets executed just before initialising the webdriver session and test framework. It allows you
 * to manipulate configurations depending on the capability or spec.
 * @param {Object} config wdio configuration object
 * @param {Array.<Object>} capabilities list of capabilities details
 * @param {Array.<String>} specs List of spec file paths that are to be run
 * @param {String} cid worker id (e.g. 0-0)
 */
// beforeSession: function (config, capabilities, specs, cid) {
// },
/**
 * Gets executed before test execution begins. At this point you can access to all global
 * variables like `browser`. It is the perfect place to define custom commands.
 * @param {Array.<Object>} capabilities list of capabilities details
 * @param {Array.<String>} specs        List of spec file paths that are to be run
 * @param {Object}         browser      instance of created browser/device session
 */
// before: function (capabilities, specs) {
// },
/**
 * Runs before a WebdriverIO command gets executed.
 * @param {String} commandName hook command name
 * @param {Array} args arguments that command would receive
 */
// beforeCommand: function (commandName, args) {
// },
/**
 * Hook that gets executed before the suite starts
 * @param {Object} suite suite details
 */
// beforeSuite: function (suite) {
// },
/**
 * Function to be executed before a test (in Mocha/Jasmine) starts.
 */
// beforeTest: function (test, context) {
// },
/**
 * Hook that gets executed _before_ a hook within the suite starts (e.g. runs before calling
 * beforeEach in Mocha)
 */
// beforeHook: function (test, context) {
// },
/**
 * Hook that gets executed _after_ a hook within the suite starts (e.g. runs after calling
 * afterEach in Mocha)
 */
// afterHook: function (test, context, { error, result, duration, passed, retries }) {
// },
/**
 * Function to be executed after a test (in Mocha/Jasmine only)
 * @param {Object}  test             test object
 * @param {Object}  context          scope object the test was executed with
 * @param {Error}   result.error     error object in case the test fails, otherwise `undefined`
 * @param {Any}     result.result    return object of test function
 * @param {Number}  result.duration  duration of test
 * @param {Boolean} result.passed    true if test has passed, otherwise false
 * @param {Object}  result.retries   informations to spec related retries, e.g. `{ attempts: 0, limit: 0 }`
 */
// afterTest: function(test, context, { error, result, duration, passed, retries }) {
// },


/**
 * Hook that gets executed after the suite has ended
 * @param {Object} suite suite details
 */
// afterSuite: function (suite) {
// },
/**
 * Runs after a WebdriverIO command gets executed
 * @param {String} commandName hook command name
 * @param {Array} args arguments that command would receive
 * @param {Number} result 0 - command success, 1 - command error
 * @param {Object} error error object if any
 */
// afterCommand: function (commandName, args, result, error) {
// },
/**
 * Gets executed after all tests are done. You still have access to all global variables from
 * the test.
 * @param {Number} result 0 - test pass, 1 - test fail
 * @param {Array.<Object>} capabilities list of capabilities details
 * @param {Array.<String>} specs List of spec file paths that ran
 */
// after: function (result, capabilities, specs) {
// },
/**
 * Gets executed right after terminating the webdriver session.
 * @param {Object} config wdio configuration object
 * @param {Array.<Object>} capabilities list of capabilities details
 * @param {Array.<String>} specs List of spec file paths that ran
 */
// afterSession: function (config, capabilities, specs) {
// },
/**
 * Gets executed after all workers got shut down and the process is about to exit. An error
 * thrown in the onComplete hook will result in the test run failing.
 * @param {Object} exitCode 0 - success, 1 - fail
 * @param {Object} config wdio configuration object
 * @param {Array.<Object>} capabilities list of capabilities details
 * @param {<Object>} results object containing test results
 */
// onComplete: function(exitCode, config, capabilities, results) {
// },
/**
* Gets executed when a refresh happens.
* @param {String} oldSessionId session ID of the old session
* @param {String} newSessionId session ID of the new session
*/
// onReload: function(oldSessionId, newSessionId) {
// }
```

}

Commented out this line: "services: ['selenium-standalone']," and stopped getting this error: "INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onPrepare hook"

Hope this would help somebody.